# kingfisher not showing image

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, printing

So I am using kingfisher as people have suggested its the way to go with remote images.

However I have a func that is meant to load now playing info

```
func nowplaying(){
    let jsonURLString = "https://api.drn1.com.au/station/playing"
            guard let feedurl = URL(string: jsonURLString) else { return }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: feedurl) { (data,response,err)
                in

                guard let data = data else { return }

                do{
                    let nowplaying = try JSONDecoder().decode(Nowplayng.self, from: data)


                    nowplaying.data.forEach {
                        self.artist.text = $0.track.artist
                        self.song.text = $0.track.title

                        //self.artist.textAlignment = .center
                        //self.song.textAlignment = .center
                        print($0.track.title)

                        if let strUrl = nowplaying.data.first?.track.imageurl {
                                                        self.imageurl.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl), placeholder: nil)

                        }
                        //self.imageurl.setImage(with: $0.track.imageurl)

                   }

                }catch let jsonErr{
                print("error json ", jsonErr)
                }


      }.resume()
}
```

but while the song title and artist shows the image does not.

Comment: can you add the image(String), you get in parameter.

Comment: @SGDev it seems to die at  - let imaurl = URL(string: image) as that returns a Nil

Comment: I know bro, but the issue in ypur image by which you get nil imaurl.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: seems like `image` is not a valid url.

Comment: @RussellHarrower what is the value of strUrl?, issue in your url only. you can use encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually url contains `spaces` that need to be percentage encoding.

```
if var strUrl = nowplaying.data.first?.track.imageurl {

    strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
    self.imageurl.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl), placeholder: nil)

}
```